# Unified technology for software update

Tags: updates, auto-update, software-distribution

It is cumbersome to update different kinds of software one by one. In my case,

- For the Ubuntu Linux OS, I periodically do `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` (this part can be automated).
- For Ruby language, I have to do particular things to upgrade.
- For Ruby libraries (gem), I have to periodically do `gem update` or `gem update --system`.
- For JQuery library, I have to periodically check its website and download the latest version.
- And so on.

I can write a script to automatically do these things, but it would be nice if there were a cross-platform unified established way where a user can just register all the software they want to be automatically updated, and a software will periodically check the relevant websites for updates and notice the user and/or automatically do the update when there is such update.

Does such technology exist? If not, what will be a promising line for such technology in the future? I have a feeling that it could be done by using something like RSS feed, where software developers will publish feeds whenever they update a software, and a specific reader takes care of the update process.

Answer (score 1):

No. And it never will. This kind of luxury comes with a price called "gated community". But then it does not apply to ALL software...